# Preventing additional connections in the socket io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

How to **only** **allow** **access** to connections from the app in nodejs and **socketio**?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to pass a JWT with the connection like

```
           socket = io.connect(server, {

            "transports": ['websocket'],
            query: {
              token: JWTTOKEN,
            },
           "forceNew":true

          });
```

On your socket server you decode the token, if not then don't let them connect. The client request the token each time then its passed to the server for connection.